# select name from whole database from all Table

Tags: c#, mysql

how do I find a name from tables in MySQL database

my database name **college_management**

its contain many tables all of this table have column name "q_name"

i want find name like "john"

i have try this

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE column_name ='q_name'
```

so , this query bring me all columns name from database
what i want show the name of this column "q_name"

for example when i make **textbox** with suggest name that will display the name i want

**update**

i reach to this

```
SELECT q_name FROM `db_name.tables_name` WHERE (CONVERT(q_name USING utf8) LIKE '%john%')
```

how to make its general in all tables not in one

Comment: You must use dynamic SQL (prepared statement) for to solve.

Comment: can you be more specific? do you mean that you're trying to find all records in all tables where there is a column called `q_name` with a value of `'john'` ? or...? and how does this relate to the textbox? surely if they typo `'john'` they'll just get back a lot of `'john'`s - not sure how that helps them?

Comment: SELECT COLUMN_NAME seems pointless did you mean select table_name?

Comment: @marc-gravell yes I want find this name in all records in all tables in specific column name call q_name

Comment: @p-salmon its just an example what I'm tried to

Comment: @Star why not just write a query that aggregates results from the *expected* tables *today*? trying to do this dynamically is IMO a really really bad idea, and is *incredibly* unusual

Comment: I can't because i allow user to generate this table with column name q_name so i don't know what the user will named the tables

Comment: Hence my previous comment.

Comment: then you're going to have to join `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` to get all of the table names, and generate SQL from the results of that, then execute the sql

Comment: @MarcGravell please see the update above

Comment: @Star again: you're going to have to join to the sys-tables metadata and use the table name in your `select`; however, you need to *generate* the `select` queries and then execute that *separately* via dynamic SQL. Again, this is not a trivial scenario.